# Font-Awesome not loading in Asset-Pipeline for Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, asset-pipeline, font-awesome

I'm using CodeSleeve's asset-pipeline to manage my stylesheets on my Laravel 4. Everything in the application.css is working except for font-awesome. I have font-awesome.min.css located in the stylesheet folder,

```
stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css
```

and the fonts are in a fonts folder within the stylesheets directory like

```
stylesheets/fonts
```

However, when i load the page, I cannot use icons like

```
<i class="icon-warning-sign"></i>
```

It just comes up blank. I have spent all day trying solutions I found online but none seems to be working. The problem here is probably how to correctly load the fonts when using assets-pipeline in Laravel 4.

I would like suggestions that would work in both production and development environment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in the public directory , create a folder fonts, inside of it add the font files

like this
public/

```
  /fonts
        / here add your font files
```

otherwise it won't work, I had the same problem before

hope it helps